# Vinculo de dados no SQL

Tags: sql

Eu realmente não manjo quase nada de banco de dados e afins, mas estou fazendo um sistema de "admin" aqui para um cliente e me questionei sobre o seguinte ponto:

Tenho duas tabelas, uma que salva as imagens em si, com o *link* e tudo e outra que salva o evento, nela tem um campo chamado `images`, o qual eu iria preencher com um JSON com os ID's da tabela `images`, gostaria de saber se isso é "cornice" como diz um amigo meu, se for qual a melhor solução?, ahh vou deixar aqui o SQL das tabelas para ficar mais fácil a visualização.

```
-- Table eventos
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eventos (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment ,
  slug VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  tittle text NOT NULL ,
  content text NOT NULL ,
  data date NOT NULL ,
  images text NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, slug)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ENGINE=MyISAM;

-- Table images
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS images (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment ,
  title VARCHAR(255) ,
  slug VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, slug)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: Julgo que a tabela imagens é que deveria ter um campo que fizesse referência ao `id` do registo na tabela eventos. Isto claro se cada imagem só pertencer a um evento.

Comment: então, mas ai ela se tornaria uma tabela com uma FK vinda de eventos certo? e tipo, tenho uma tabela que usa o id das imagens como referencia, voce sugere criar tipo uma tabela eventos_imgs e fazer o vinculo nessa tabela?

Comment: Se cada imagem só pertencer a um evento(relação OneToMany) basta a FK se uma imagem puder pertencer a mais de um evento(relação ManyToMany) então sim é necessário criar uma terceira tabela.

Comment: Isso é o que a gente chama de XGH: http://helio.loureiro.eng.br/index.php/pessoal/39-blog/240-extreme-go-horse-xgh

Answer (score 2):

O termo *"cornice"* que o seu amigo utilizou provavelmente se refere ao uso de más práticas, pois dar manutenção em código mal-feito é o tipo de coisa que no Brasil chamamos de *"trabalho de corno"* ou *"castigo pra corno"*.

Usar o JSON como você descreveu pode ser visto como má prática, pelos seguintes motivos:

- Não é nada intuitivo trabalhar com JSON na linguagem SQL pura - talvez um ou outro sistema de banco de dados te auxilie nisso, mas acho que isso seria mais fácil de encontrar em bancos não-relacionais (ou seja, bem diferentes do trio SQL Server, Oracle e MySQL);
- Mas principalmente mesmo - existe um relacionamento muito forte entre fotos e eventos. Os bancos de dados relacionais têm esse nome porque têm formas bem estruturadas para lidar com esses relacionamentos. Ao fazer o relacionamento através de texto em colunas, você faz o que tecnicamente se chama de *"relacionamento fraco"*, que é quando você assume a responsabilidade de garantir os relacionamentos no lugar do banco. Isso é uma forma grave de **reinvenção da roda**, e quanto mais o seu sistema se tornar complexo, mais você vai sofrer com retrabalho e depressão.

A forma mais indicada de lidar com isso é fazer um relacionamento com chaves estrangeiras. Nesse caso, como um evento pode ter várias fotos, mas uma foto só faz parte de um evento (certo?), a tabela de fotos deve ser **filha** da tabela de eventos. A tabela de fotos precisa de uma coluna, do mesmo tipo que a coluna de ID da tabela de eventos. Essa coluna específica será uma **chave estrangeira**, que apontará para a chave primária na tabela de eventos. Você pode chamar essa coluna de `id_evento` ou algum outro nome que seja auto-descritivo.

O efeito disso é que, por padrão:

- você não poderá apagar eventos que tenham fotos associadas;
- toda foto já deverá ser inserida no banco apontando para um evento.

Isso é uma forma de garantir a integridade dos dados. Não existirá foto sem evento (embora possa haver evento sem foto). As regras desse relacionamento podem ser alteradas... Por exemplo, a exclusão de um evento pode excluir automaticamente todas as fotos.

Daí pra frente é tudo configuração. Só dá para saber qual é a melhor configuração ao se "por a mão na massa" e mexer no sistema, então não adianta perguntar a "melhor" forma de se configurar os relacionamentos aqui. O que eu recomendo é que brinque bastante com isso, pois o aprendizado pela experiência é muito superior a qualquer outra forma de aprendizado.

E para consultar todas as fotos de um evento, você pode usar [INNER JOIN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/1658):

```
SELECT
    i.*
FROM
    images i INNER JOIN eventos e
WHERE
    i.id_evento = e.id
```

Comment: A título de pura curiosidade, o PostgreSQL possui [tipo de dados `JSON` nativo](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) desde a versão 9.2, com indexação apropriada, extensões ao SQL e tudo o mais...

Comment: @nunks.lol se você escrever uma resposta elaborando sobre isso já tem meu voto positivo garantido.

Comment: escrevo sim, só não sei se é apropriado para esta questão... O que você respondeu é a forma correta e canônica de resolver o problema de vinculação "um para muitos" colocado na pergunta. O tipo de dados JSON foi colocado no PostgreSQL pelo pessoal do Heroku com objetivo justamente de suprir necessidades "NoSQL", como armazenamento de documentos estruturados.